# Creating After Trigger

Tags: database, oracle, triggers

I am trying to build a simple database on my own time before my SQL for Business course starts to better understand a few concepts since I am a struggling beginner. I want to Create an AFTER trigger on my Hotel table that deletes any records from the Rooms table that match (:old.HOTEL_ID). I've been reading up on triggers online, but I am still having trouble understanding how to code the body of my trigger. I am using Oracle since it feels more comfortable for me in my inexperience. I was hoping the community here could give me some insight on this.

I tried

```
CREATE TRIGGER tblHotel_T1 
  AFTER DELETE ON tblHotel 
  FOR EACH ROW
```

And I had the

```
DELETE FROM tblrooms 
  WHERE hotHotel_ID=:old.hotHotel_ID;
```

I am just unsure how to enter the trigger into Oracle, since I first began using SQL Studio Manager. Even though Oracle seems a lot simpler, I am not use to the user interface.

Then Oracle supplies a "WHEN" field, and then a "Trigger body" field. This is where I become confused because I'm not sure how to enter it all in.

Answer (score 1):

If you post what you've tried already, that would help us help you by showing us where you're going wrong.

It sounds like the trigger you want is something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_hotel_del
  AFTER DELETE ON hotel
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM rooms
   WHERE hotel_id = :old.hotel_id;
END;
```

I'm assuming that your goal is to create a trigger that fires after a delete (it would seem odd to delete all the rooms when you inserted or updated a row in the `HOTEL` table).

Of course, in reality, you would create a foreign key constraint in order to enforce this rather than creating a trigger.

Comment: Do I need a When clause?

Comment: @LynetteShatto - Not based on anything I see in your question, no.  Do you want to fire the trigger only in certain situations when a row is deleted from `hotel`?  If so, what are those situations?